# cats claws becomes less sharper every time they use it

Tags: cats

OK so sometimes cats scratches tree in order to keep their claws sharp
so is it true that every time a cat or any other feline uses it claw, there claws become less sharper

Answer (score 3):

A cat claw will get less sharp over time and this is why cats sharpen their claws; a cat's claw is layered like an onion, so when a cat sharpens its claw the outer layer falls off exposing a fresh sharp claw.

If you take a look at your cat's scratching post you will probably find the outer shell of your cat's claws. A cat has two ways of sharpening their claws: one is by scratching and the other is by using its teeth to remove the outer layer of the claw.

Most cats have retractable claws on the front legs. The claws on the hind legs cannot be retracted fully, but they still stay fairly sharp - however, it is nothing compared to the claws on the front legs.

By retracting the claws on the front legs, they stay protected against wear when they walk; when a cat catches larger prey animals, the cat uses the powerful hind legs and claws to tear the prey's belly open; cats do the same when they fight each other.

Comment: so they get less sharper everytime they use them or if don't use them

Comment: @user17566 Using claws naturally dulls them. Cats scratch things (like posts or trees) to break off the old, dull top layer to expose the new, sharp layer beneath.